# What is the proper way to upgrade kernel in 18.04 when using nvidia drivers?

Tags: nvidia, kernel

I'd like to update the kernel from 4.15 to 4.18.5 using ukuu, but I heard that there are issues with this when using nvidia video cards.  I'm currently using drivers from `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`.  I read that after updating the kernel you need to build new kernel modules for the nvidia drivers.  What I'm wondering is, does the ppa already have kernel modules built for the kernels available through ukuu, or will I have to build them myself? Here what I was thinking of doing:

1. Remove proprietary nvidia drivers so it falls back to nouveau
2. Update to kernel 4.18.5 using ukuu
3. Reboot
4. Install proprietary nvidia drivers from `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`

Will this work?  If not, what is the correct way to do things?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I strongly recommend not to "update" kernels using ukuu, as these are unsupported kernels built for testing purposes. Wait for Ubuntu 18.04.2 to come out, when you will be able to update to newer kernel using the new **hardware enablement stack**.

Comment: You probably fo not need to remove the nvidia driver first and you may or may not need to reinstall it after. Give it a try